# Custom sort on Kendo Scheduler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Is there a way to custom sort the kendo scheduler?  I am using a kendo scheduler on an MVC project and I have sorted the data the way I would like to see it on the calendar on the back end, but the calendar seems to sort it automatically in time sequence.  I would like to sort it on a different parameter.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the goals of the scheduler widget is to display the events in the time slots they are occurring. As a results events are always sorted by their time. The only way to implement custom sorting is via custom scheduler view. The [custom view](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-view-0286055de51d) code library project shows how this could be done.

Comment: This is what I figured.  The customer was wanting the Month view with some grouping on a type.  Thanks for the help.